# Check from database version in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a .NET application that I'm migrating to Yii2. In the database I have a table `VariablesGlobales` with a field named `Version`. I need to check the value of this field with a param named `minDBversion` to be sure it is running the right DB version with my application.

My problem is I need to check it in all applications (not only in one controller) because it is possible that the client has access to any part of it. I was checking `requirement.php` from Yii2 but I think that´s not the good way because it has been designed for components and server requirements.

I hope you shed light on the situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to to check something in all your Yii application and not only in one controller you should take advantage of the usage of [Components](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0/).

With components you can injects automatically in every controller of your app any kind of logic.

The base to extend you controller is:

```
namespace app\components;
use yii\web\Controller;
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean I create this and after extend my controllers from basecontroller instead of Controller?

Comment: Exactly. Once you've done that, you are ready to put any kind of logic inside your component that will be triggered for all your children controllers. For instance, you can use methods beforeAction() and afterAction() to add code that will be evaluated right before and right after accessing an anction in your child controller.